# How to attach interface to other website through DOM JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have interface of "box chat" so i want attach it to other customer's website through script tag. I think that interface have been converted to DOM file javacript. So i created file js "http://skynet-software.com/this/script.js" and link it into customer's interface. But my script not working and style of customer's website have been affected by file css in "box chat".
Script of "box chat" only work when i place

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So how can my script of box chat work well and my css only work in box chat.

Link demo : http://skynet-software.com/this/